# Newton's Principia: Astronomical prerequisites?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, soft-question

I am planning to read the Principia but I currently have no knowledge about Astronomy. What astronomy prerequisites do I need to understand the Principia? I would prefer older books (or "treatises"), anything from 1600's+, as I don't really like the modern textbook style. I heard that studying Copernican astronomy is a good idea, but the only books I know on this are Copernicus's book (English translation available) and Gassendi's Astronomy (No english translation; I can't read latin)

Comment: Why not simply start reading Principia and when you come across some astronomy thing that you don't know enough about, then you can search for old texts specifically about those concepts

Comment: @Jim: I'm not good at this way of learning, unless I plan to read the book twice, which I don't. I tried it before on a number theory book, but I ended up with a superficial understanding; when I read it the second time, many new things made sense and it all slotted together nicely. I just don't think I'm good at working backwards from material to gain understanding... Besides, I would prefer to have a working knowledge of astronomy before reading the book, rather than a streamlined approach where I know "just" enough to understanding the propositions (which is implied by your suggestion)

Comment: @Jim: Another thing that is slightly unrealistic regarding your suggestion: I know NOTHING about astronomy. If I randomly look up things in references (online or in book form), I will not understand the terminology/notation they use to explain that thing. So even if I agreed to use this method, it is highly unlikely that it would work.

Comment: Don't read Newton's *Principia* if you want to learn physics. The reason to read Newton's *Principia* is to study early Enlightenment thinking on the sciences, but that is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Why not? How you learn a subject can influence your thinking later on. Newton himself learned geometry from Descarte's Geometria (BEFORE reading Euclid's elements) and ended up being one of the most acute analysts of his time. Of course, it was a struggle, but such struggles are known to bring with them great rewards such as scientific maturity.

Comment: Well, there's the thing that a LOT has been learned between now and then.  While absolutely clear and brilliant for the 1600s, the methods of the Principia are pretty blunt by today's standards.  In particular, there was not yet a clear consensus on the notions of conservation of momentum and energy.  A modern treatment of the problems of orbital mechanics would start with the Lagrangian formulation, as well, which is a better groundwork for learning about quantum mechanics, anyway.

Comment: @user45220 learn physics however you want. David is simply trying to tell you that you will not gain much insight into physics from Principia. Also, if you try to learn modern physics starting from ancient times and working your way up, it will take a long time and will most likely contain confusing contradictions

Comment: Also, isn't the fact that Newton learned from a distilled version of the Elements a great reason to start with a more modern treatment, rather than going to the original sources?  I'm not necessarily against original sources in all cases, but here, I think it might be true.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer - Exactly. Newton's *Principia* is written in a rather archaic and hard to understand form (at least from a modern perspective). He didn't use algebra in the book, and the little calculus used is very deeply buried in the synthetic geometry approach used throughout the book. He didn't use vectors; how could he? They wouldn't be invented for another 200 years.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: Point taken. But then again, are modern books of nowadays really equivalent to "modern" books back then? What is the physics equivalent of Descarte's Geometria today? Do we really have physics books that are (a) accessible to high school/undergraduate students, and at the same time (b) written by a master in the subject. I don't think this is true I'm afraid. Times have changed.

Answer (score 1):

A few weeks ago I was at a rare books store in Las Vegas and was able to page through a second edition copy of Principia from 1723. Just flipping (carefully, it was a $15,000 book) to random pages landed me on:

- Newton showing that the same force that pulls apples to the ground also keeps the moon in orbit.
- Newton describing how light diffracts when encountering a narrow slit.
- And, for good measure, Newton inventing calculus.

Unfortunately, the book was in Latin (the original language of science), so I couldn't get much detail out of it (not to mention the shop keepers getting more nervous with every page turn). In any case, from what I could discern from the words I recognized and the diagrams, not much astronomy knowledge is needed. What concerned Newton was the motion of the planets, sun, and moon across the sky (that is, angular measurements similar to longitude and latitude) and how their real motion could be derived and used to prove his ideas for how gravity worked. If you can follow geometric reasoning--like how parallax works--then you'll be fine.

Back in Newton's time, almost nothing was known about what the lights in the sky were. Some lights moved with respect to other lights, some didn't. The near surface of the moon was pretty well mapped out because it's so close, but the composition and nature of other heavenly bodies was unknown. The geometry of their motion was the research area of the day to explain things like the retrograde motion of Mars. The elliptical shapes of orbits had been puzzled out by Kepler, but the details of their motion required Newton's ideas on gravity.

Other than brushing up on trigonometry and other geometry, dive in.

Comment: I highly doubt this, or at least it needs to be much more specific. First of all, it's not just any old geometry that you learn in high school. You need to learn the geometry of conic sections well before you can understand most of the proofs. Second, I definitely know that astronomy is at least a minor prerequisite, since Newton himself recommends that you need to know it ("the Copernican system") in order to be able to understand his book in a letter to Richard Bentley.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need english classes more than anything. I tried to read the to english translated version (by Andrew Motte) just before I started my university studies...well let's just say that I didn't make it through the *motivation for the translation*, let alone reading the actual text.

In any case, from what I remember there were 
**a lot of geometry**, which really surprised me because back then I thought Newton would introduce and use Calculus extensively (to my best knowledge, he later did this in Optiks).

Also there were some **tables of the planets**.

It was really nice to just have that book, because I wanted to have the feeling that I was reading what Newton actually wrote, but then I realized that, hey, I'm reading a translation, Newton wrote it in Latin, so that was a fail in many ways I guess haha.

I might give it another try when I retire in 100 years.

Comment: You can still buy "the central argument" Densmore. Apparently this is translated as accurately as possible, but it isn't the whole Principia.